# JetBrains dotMemory: Unable to import the dump: 64-bit dumps of 32-bit processes are currently not supported

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, jetbrains-ide, dotmemory

I have downloaded `ProcDump` from Windows Sysinternals site. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procdump

I have used below command to initiate dump collection.

```
       procdump -ma <process_name>
```

Here is the command line output

```
       [08:17:43] Dump 1 initiated: 
       E:\SSDT\Procdump\WindowsService.exe_180926_081743.dmp
       [08:17:47] Dump 1 writing: Estimated dump file size is 2309 MB.
       [08:17:59] Dump 1 complete: 2310 MB written in 16.5 seconds
       [08:18:00] Dump count reached.
```

Now, I am trying to import it in `JetBrains dotMemory` but unfortunately I am getting below error prompt.

> ---
>
> ### dotMemory
>
> Unable to import the dump: 64-bit dumps of 32-bit processes are currently not >supported. Please use a 32-bit tool to take a dump. For example, >%WinDir%\SysWOW64\taskmgr.exe is a 32-bit version of Task Manager.

What is meaning of `64-bit dumps of 32-bit processes`? I have tried to create dump from both the EXE's from `ProcDump`, But I get the same message prompt.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Some of the dump-taking tools (TaskManager for instance) write dumps in a 64-bit format even for 32-bit applications.
ClrMd (which is currently used in background for dump processing in dotMemory) doesn't handle this situation well (addressing issues).
So there is an additional check in dotMemory which detects if this is the case on early stages and shows the message.

Normally Procdump is known for producing proper dumps independently from the procdump bitness.
But it looks like in your scenario something is different.
Could you please upload dumps produced by both procdump.exe and procdump64.exe to https://uploads.services.jetbrains.com/ and mention the names?
This will help the team to investigate the case.

Comment: Do I have any alternative steps?

Answer (score 1):

As the documentation says, if you start %WinDir%\SysWOW64\taskmgr.exe (32bit version of task manager) you can right click on your process then create the dump (for your 32bit application